# What are some good tea party snacks for toddlers?

Tags: toddler, food

There is a tea party in the kindergarten group, for 2 to 3 year olds.

Which cool and unusual snacks (not the common things like candies and pastry) would be a good idea to bring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will depend on the region and the number of food allergies that the children have, so you will definitely want to check on that first.  Considering that these are 2-3 year olds you're probably not going to get much in the way of adventurous eating either but here are some things our adventurous 3 year old ate:

- Roasted Mushrooms, probably could do small stuffed ones
- Mini Quiche
- Maki Rolls, the ones we had were a variety of crab leg, avocado or cucumber but nothing spicy
- Meringue Mushrooms (a sort of pain to make unless you are used to it but amusing)
- Cucumber Sandwiches, no tea party is complete without!

I could probably think of a few more but this should get you started.

Comment: Wasn't aware of cucumber sandwiches before (I'm from Russia) but they really made a party, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Dips like hummus seem quite popular with bread sticks and sticks of cucumber, peppers or carrots.

cherry/baby tomatoes

mini quiches

also spanish tortilla (potatoe omlette) went down very well at the last 2-3 year olds party we had.

Not sure if these are cool or unusual though...

Comment: Great ideas! Just please remember to cut the cherry tomatoes: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/37659/what-is-the-evidence-on-the-danger-of-feeding-whole-blueberries-and-grapes-to-in

Answer (score 2):

Random suggestions follow :

- Chocolate crispie / cornflake cakes (home made; involve kids - but perhaps they fall into your Candie category?)
- Mini sausage rolls
- Cherry/baby tomatoes
- Breadsticks
- Gingerbread men - again could be home made, but perhaps too sweet?
- Scones / buns - again could be home made.
- Rice cakes/crackers (we have a brand called Snack-a-Jack which seems popular with my kids)
- Apple/Orange/Banana slices

Comment: Please remember to cut the cherry tomatoes and sausages: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/37659/what-is-the-evidence-on-the-danger-of-feeding-whole-blueberries-and-grapes-to-in/#comment79172_37660

Answer (score 1):

- dried fruits, like dried apricots, prunes, dried apples etc.
- non allergenic fruits like apples, bananas etc.
- juices

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the items I've seen that children really go for:

- **Bananitos**, if you can get them. These are teeny tiny bananas, the size of an adults' thumb. Very cute and kids love them.
- **Crazy Jelly/Jello**. You make several different types of jelly and then scoop chunks out of, say, the strawberry, raspberry and blackcurrant and put them into an almost-set apple jelly, along with bits of strawberry, apple, blueberries or pears.
- **Marzipan Characters**. Buy some marzipan for cooking and some natural food colouring. Roll the marzipan into balls of different sizes and make Lego-style people and animals. Needs some imagination and an allergy warning on the marzipan (made from almond paste)
- **Scotch Pancakes**. These are small, but thick pancakes that usually have raisins too. They're best warmed, but kids love them.

Comment: That's a lot of sugar...?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. It's a party, so there tends to be treats, and they don't happen every day.